# Ubuntu Boot Freeze

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, freeze

I got problem when I want to boot with my ubuntu 16.04.1 on hp 242 g1.
I dual boot with Windows.

It freezes in the final dot.

In recovery mode it instead direct me to console. Then I logged in.

Well I'm still able to code in vim though

What should I do to resolve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Intel or Nvidia?

Comment: I use Intel hd graphics 4000

Comment: Hey do you know what should I do ??

Comment: There are many possible causes. For now I can just suggest, in console after logging in: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. If any errors edit and add that information. Also what Ubuntu rele4ase/version it is.